# What to look for in bad pg_dump log

Tags: postgresql, cron, monitoring, dump

We want to programmatically detect errors in cron scheduled pg_dumps.

Apart from checking whether or not the log file ends with `pg_dump: saving database definition`:

What other tell-tale strings are there to grep for in order to programmatically check if the dump is OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` the output for mentions of "ERROR:".

Comment: I happen to have some tables with the string "error" in their names. That would yield false alerts.

Comment: Look for 'ERROR:' in all caps followed by a colon.